# Grouping multiple MySql queries

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a simple query as listed below

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM users WHERE group_id = 1
```

This works great until, I then start adding `LIKE` queries, chained with `OR` statements to the end.

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM users 
 WHERE group_id = 1 
   AND id LIKE $searchterm 
    OR name LIKE $searchterm 
    OR email LIKE $searchterm
```

Suddenly my `WHERE` clause is no longer upheld and results with a 'group_id' of 2 or 3 are retrieved.

Is there a way I can group `WHERE` clauses so that they are always upheld or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with the query first - you need to use brackets for the WHERE clause to be interpreted correctly:

```
SELECT id, name, email 
  FROM users 
 WHERE group_id = 1 
   AND (    id LIKE $searchterm 
       OR name LIKE $searchterm 
       OR email LIKE $searchterm)
```

I'd be looking at using Full Text Search (FTS) instead, so you could use:

```
SELECT id, name, email 
  FROM users 
 WHERE group_id = 1 
   AND MATCH(id, name, email) AGAINST ($searchterm)
```

Mind that the `USERS` table needs to be MyISAM...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want

```
email FROM users WHERE group_id = 1 AND (id LIKE $searchterm OR name LIKE $searchterm OR email LIKE $searchterm)
```

Here is the mysql [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) table